# HtAccess replace folder by another if virtual subdomain adding

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, server, configuration

I want to create a "dev" folder for all my sites, for can programming without perturbate the real site positioned in folder "web"

If i type "SubDomain1.Domain.fr" currently i'm directed to:

```
domain.fr/folder1/folder2/folder3/web/MySite1/index.php
```

Or "SubDomain2.Domain.fr" currently i'm directed to;

```
domain.fr/folder1/folder2/folder3/web/MySite2/index.php
```

etc ... and it works very well.

But I would like for all my sites, to replace the name of a folder "/web/" by "/dev/" only if i add another virtual SubDomain "dev." before the actual SubDomain

If i type "dev.SubDomain1.Domain.fr" i want be directed to:

```
domain.fr/folder1/folder2/folder3/dev/MySite1/index.php
```

If someone have an idea for do this miracle, i wish you a very good day

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: .htaccess isn't the right tool for the job.  I'd recommend configuring the `<VirtualHost>` for the subdomain to point to a different `DirectoryRoot` in the Apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks STEPHEN for your help, I take a look to the <VirtualHost> :-)